# How to add a role to a user DiscordJS

Tags: discord

trying to give a user a role although it keeps erroring with " Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')" looked in alot of different places can't figure it out

code:
`interaction.user.roles.add('1081869257043869767')`

interaction is a application interaction

when i run console.log(interaction) everything is there (verifying it is a correct interaction)

tried users.roles.add, erroed with Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
interaction.guild.members.cache.get(interaction.user.id).roles.add("0000000000")
```